# NIFI - How to connect to Kerberos enabled KUDU

Tags: kerberos, apache-nifi, apache-kudu

How can I connect from NIFI to a Kerberos enabled Kudu?

I only see one processor to access Kudu - `PutKUDU` and it doesn't support Kerberos. I haven't seen anywhere online any discussion regarding connecting to Kudu with Kerberos. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is being worked on now and there is a pull request to add support for keberos to PutKudu:

https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/3279 - NIFI-5984: Enabled Kerberos Authentication for PutKudu

I don't believe there is a way to do it without the work in that pull request.